# Detect position:fixed with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, mobile

I am trying to use Kangax's script from here: http://kangax.github.com/cft/ to detect those browsers that "properly" implement position:fixed as desktop browsers do, compared to mobile browsers so I can use jQuery to fake it on mobile browsers.

The code from Kangax works fine. However when I incorporate it into my page it doesn't. I think it must be some obvious mistake. Any help would be really appreciated!

```
////Detect whether position:fixed works (mobile browsers). Use JS to position #navwrap if not.
  //Kangax's script - begins at "function" on the next line.
function detected() {
    var container = document.body;
    if (document.createElement &&
    container && container.appendChild && container.removeChild) {
        var el = document.createElement("div");
        if (!el.getBoundingClientRect) {
            return null;
        }
        el.innerHTML = "x";
        el.style.cssText = "position:fixed;top:100px;";
        container.appendChild(el);
        var originalHeight = container.style.height, originalScrollTop = container.scrollTop;
        container.style.height = "3000px";
        container.scrollTop = 500;
        var elementTop = el.getBoundingClientRect().top;
        container.style.height = originalHeight;
        var isSupported = elementTop === 100;
        container.removeChild(el);
        container.scrollTop = originalScrollTop;
        return isSupported;
    }
    return null;
};
if (detected()) {
    alert ('non-mobile');
}
    else {
        alert ('mobile');
    }
```

In case it helps, the original code (stripped as much as possible):

```
<body>
<h2>Position Fixed Test</h2>    

<script>    
(function(__global){
// make sure `window` resolves to a global object
var window = this;
var features = { };
features.IS_POSITION_FIXED_SUPPORTED = (features.__IS_POSITION_FIXED_SUPPORTED = function () {
var container = document.body;
if (document.createElement &&
  container && container.appendChild && container.removeChild) {
  var el = document.createElement("div");
  if (!el.getBoundingClientRect) {
      return null;
  }
  el.innerHTML = "x";
  el.style.cssText = "position:fixed;top:100px;";
  container.appendChild(el);
  var originalHeight = container.style.height, originalScrollTop = container.scrollTop;
  container.style.height = "3000px";
  container.scrollTop = 500;
  var elementTop = el.getBoundingClientRect().top;
  container.style.height = originalHeight;
  var isSupported = elementTop === 100;
  container.removeChild(el);
  container.scrollTop = originalScrollTop;
  return isSupported;
}
return null;
})();
__global.__features = features;
})(this);

(function(){
function detect() {
 for (var i=0; i<1; i++) {
  var testResult = __features['IS_POSITION_FIXED_SUPPORTED'];
  alert ( testResult );
  i++;
 }
};
detect(); 
})();
</script>

</body>
```

Comment: The original example on http://kangax.github.com/cft/ sucessfully differentiates between desktop and mobile browsers, but mine doesn't. I guess I am not testing for null vs isSupported correctly??

Comment: what do you see and when

Comment: I always get the alert "not-supported". 
I have added the original code above. That code can tell whether the browser is mobile or not. Mine cannot. 
Cheers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorted. Thanks for the input.

Turns out my version of the code runs fine, but it has to be placed in the body of the page. If it is in the Head, even within a DOM Ready call it doesn't.

Just have to find out why now! But at least the code works.

Answer (score 1):

I guess that you are always getting `non-mobile`. You are checking that `detected` exists not executing the function. Change the end of your JavaScript to

```
if (detected()) {
  alert ('non-mobile');
}
else {
    alert ('mobile');
}
```

Is there a reason that you are creating the function as an anonymous function assigned to a variable and not as a named function e.g.

```
function detected(){
  // Function content.
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I incorporated that but no change :(

I have also corrected the named function vs var - just noob-ness.

Comment: What result are you getting? The code that you have provided works fine for me [http://jsfiddle.net/seRr3/](http://jsfiddle.net/seRr3/). What alert do you get?

Comment: @phil - there is nothing wrong with declaring a function as a variable, just that you can only call the function when it is within scope.

Comment: Your absolutely right that it runs and provides an alert - but not the one I'm expecting..
Regardless of whether I am testing on a mobile device or desktop I get "not-mobile". However when i run the original script on kangax.github.com/cft it sucessfully differentiates between them - see http://stickmanphotography.co.uk/box/ipad.png and http://stickmanphotography.co.uk/box/desktop.png for the output of the original.